# Given the trigonometric value of the double angle, how to find the trigonometric value taught by double？

Tags: trigonometry

Known this

```
Tan[2 A] == 2 Sqrt[2]
```

How do you evaluate its value?

```
Tan[A] ==?   Sin[A]==?   Cos[A]==?
```

Comment: You can do `slnt = Solve[Tan[2 A] == 2 Sqrt[2], A] /. C[1] -> 0` and then `Tan[A] /. slnt // FullSimplify` to get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. You can also leave `C[1]` and still do the same

Comment: Does `Solve[{2 Sqrt[2] == TrigExpand[Tan[2 a]], ta Cos[a] == Sin[a]}, ta, {Cos[a], Sin[a]}]` do what you were expecting?

Comment: @bmf      leave C[1] the result is:  ```ConditionalExpression[
  Tan[1/2 (ArcTan[
       2 Sqrt[2]] + \[Pi] ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]])], 
  ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]] \[Element] Integers]}```

Comment: @csn899 ok, I still don't understand the issue

Comment: From `Reduce[Tan[2 A] == 2 Sqrt[2], A] /. C[1] -> k`, take `FullSimplify[Table[Sin[1/2 (k Pi + ArcTan[2 Sqrt[2]])], {k, 0, 3}]]`, there are only such solutions since `Sin` has period $2\pi$.

Comment: @ 
J. M.'s persistent exhaustion
♦```Solve[{2 Sqrt[2] == TrigExpand[Tan[2 a]], tan Cos[a] == Sin[a], 
  0 <= a <= \[Pi]/2}, tan, {Cos[a], Sin[a]}]```How to add a range to the angle A There are two values, one positive and one negative. Isn't there only one positive value?

Comment: Yes, so you need to recall sign patterns for trigonometric functions, or at least recall that `tan > 0` iff `a > 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what is wanted.

```
sltn = Solve[Tan[2 A] == 2 Sqrt[2], A] // Flatten // Normal;
res = Tan[A] /. sltn;
rule = Tan[a_ + b_] :> (Tan[a] + Tan[b])/(1 - Tan[a] Tan[b]);
```

and then

```
FullSimplify /@ ((Expand /@ res) /. rule) // FullSimplify
```

> [image: fs]

So, essentially the trick is to implement the rule of the `Tan` of the sum. Likewise for the rest.

Comment: This is powerful and derives the doubly angle formula that represents tangents in terms of tangents. How do I limit the scope of A? I tried to run an error in the latter plus range. Another question, why can't the software directly use the Trigexpand command to generate a doubly angle formula that represents tangent with tangent?

Comment: TrigExpand[Tan[2 a]]==(2 Cos[a] Sin[a])/(Cos[a]^2 - Sin[a]^2)

Comment: @csn899 related to your second question: from the documentation `TrigExpand splits up sums and integer multiples that appear in arguments of trigonometric functions, and then expands out products of trigonometric functions into sums of powers, using trigonometric identities when possible.` Which means that `TrigExpand` automatically simplifies even further to `Sin` and `Cos`. That is my understanding of the matter. I don't understand what you mean by limit the scope of `A`

Comment: For example, the scope of Limit A is:0<=A<=pi/2

Comment: @csn899 You can add assumptions to `Solve` like this: `sltn = Assuming[0 <= A < 2 Pi, Solve[Tan[2 A] == 2 Sqrt[2], A]] //Flatten // Normal` essentially this fixes the values of `C[1]` so you can do it at the end to be honest